# How to properly utilize dependency injection within static context

Tags: spring

While my application is a web application, it doesn't use much of Spring's web controllers.  It's just REST (jersey) and sockets.  Only about half of my application uses dependency injection.  My application is initialized within my `main()`.

```
ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new SpringServlet());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.production.resource.ResponseCorsFilter");
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");

//add atmosphere support
ServletRegistration socketRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", new SocketInitializer());
socketRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
//socketRegistration.addMapping("/socket/*");

//deploy
logger.info("Deploying server...");
ctx.deploy(server);

server.start();

//start the production process
Production.init();

System.in.read();
server.stop();
```

Within the `Production` class I load my services via `ApplicationContextProvider`.  **Is there a better way to do this that would allow me to load all my resources via dependency injection?**

```
public static void init() {
    //add hook to trigger Production Shutdown sequence
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Production.shutdown();
        }
    }));

    logger.info("Initializing production workflows...");
    productionService = (ProductionService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("productionService");

    //load active workflows into memory
    WorkflowService workflowService = (WorkflowService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("workflowService");
    for (WorkflowEntity workflowEntity : workflowService.findActive()) {
        logger.info("      - "+workflowEntity.getName()+"");
        workflowList.add(Workflow.factory(workflowEntity));
    }

    bootup();

    logger.info("Production initialized");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way to do it because of static context.

If you can use your `init()` method in non-static way then you can do it using `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` helper class:

```
@Autowired
private ProductionService productionService;

// ... another dependencies

public void init() throws ServletException {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    // use autowired services
}
```

There is another option: you can use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` as a base class for your `Production` class. In this case you do not need  to call manually `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`. Just add dependencies and go.

Comment: If I don't want to make a service available all the time, but only for a specific method, is there a more on-demand way of autowiring a class outside of `ApplicationContextProvider`?

Comment: I do not know more on-demand way to do it. And to use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport ` you need to remove `static` keyword. Actually it will not work for you out of the box.